# Where is Mathematica in the tiobe index?

Tags: programming

I looked at http://www.tiobe.com/tiobe-index/ and cannot find Mathematica among the top 100 programming languages.

The same I see at small scale: in my research group are nearly 30 scientists, most are programming in Python, then Matlab, IDL and C, C++ and 2 people only use Mathematica (we do not have financial problems an could easily buy more licenses).

What is the reason that mathematica is not so much popular?

Comment: please take a look at this post: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1152/looking-ahead-to-wolfram-language

Comment: While I do have an opinion on this, I will answer very indirectly: try to answer what made the other systems / languages you mentioned, popular. The answer to that question will contain 80% of the answer to the one you asked.

Comment: @Rod: thank you for the link ... there everything is being discussed what I am interested in.

Comment: "Mathematica" is not among the monitored languages anymore: http://www.tiobe.com/tiobe-index/programming-languages-definition/#instances

Comment: @Karsten7. - However, Wolfram (Language) is listed and has its own [`wiki page`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfram_Language)

Comment: @BobHanlon There is no reason why Wikipedia content should have any correlation with Tiobe index. These are completely different and unrelated resources.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin - from the [`link`](http://www.tiobe.com/tiobe-index/programming-languages-definition/#instances) provided by @Karsten7., one of the three criteria used by [`TIOBE`](http://www.tiobe.com) to define what they consider a programming language and that they will track is "The language should have an own entry on Wikipedia and Wikipedia should clearly state that it concerns a programming language."

Comment: @BobHanlon Ok, you are right, I wasn't careful. I take my words back. But this probably means a necessary condition rather than sufficient, for TIOBE.

Comment: Most reply that Mathematica itself is too slow in access of variables compared to for example Fortran by a factor of 10. So the use of creating code in C or Fortran is still a need for Mathematica.

Comment: @Karsten7 Your statement is _false_ as of June 29, 2023. The (valid) link you have provided explicitly lists: `Wolfram: Mathematica, Wolfram`. Nevertheless, the _Wolfram Language_ only fares among the (not separately ranked) places 51–100.